# How can we show that a maximum matching in $G$ has $|V_1|$ edges

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, duality-theorems, matching-theory

A bipartite graph $G = (V_1, V_2, E)$, with $V_1$ and $V_2$ being the two partitions of the set of vertices, is $d$-regular provided every vertex in $G$ has degree exactly $d$.

Show that a maximum matching in $G$ has $|V_1|$ edges. I'm thinking to use standard max-flow-min-cut theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a $k$-regular bipartite graph has a perfect matching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805181/prove-that-a-k-regular-bipartite-graph-has-a-perfect-matching)

Comment: @ArsenBerk I didn't understand that answer. Can you please elaborate based on this question

Comment: Do you know Hall's Theorem? Without using it, this might be hard to prove. If you know Hall's Theorem, I can try to explain the answer given there.

Comment: I'm thinking to use max flow min cut theorem because Halls theorem was not explained to me