# Number of perfect matchings in a complete bipartite graph without any edge repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I need the number of perfect matchings in a complete bipartite graph, such that no edge is repeated in other perfect matchings. For example consider a bipartite graph with $n=6$, the complete graph with the three perfect matchings is given. No edge is repeated here. I know that the answer is $n/2$. But how to prove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reason this way. After we have found another perfect matching, we remove all the edges of this matching from our graph.  We will obtain a new regular bipartite graph for which we can use this [statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805181/prove-that-a-k-regular-bipartite-graph-has-a-perfect-matching). After that we repeat the above process. It is clear that the process will end when all the edges are exhausted.
As a result, we will get exactly $n/2$ of perfect matchings which have no edges repeated.